# Get value from a user control that add dynamically in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I wanted to add some controls by clicking on the button. and when click again, this controls repeated. and then by click to another button save value from all controls.

so I use a usercontrol(FilterParameters ) that have this controls :

```
<div class="main">
        <asp:label ID="FilterByParam" runat="server" Text="filter" ></asp:label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFilter" runat="server" CssClass="NormalTextBox" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <asp:label ID="FilterRule" runat="server" Text="Rule"></asp:label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtRule" runat="server" Width="330px" Height="50px" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
```

and I use this code in my code to load this user control( I add a placeholder to add this usercontrol) :

```
 protected void lnkAddNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int count = 0;
        if (ViewState["count"] != null)
        {
            count = (int)ViewState["count"];
        }
        count++;
        ViewState["count"] = count;
        CreateControls();
    }
private void CreateControls()
    {
        int count = 0;
        if (ViewState["count"] != null)
        {
            count = (int)ViewState["count"];
        }
 while (placeholder.Controls.Count < count)
        {
            Common.FilterParameters fp = (Common.FilterParameters)LoadControl("~/Common/FilterParameters.ascx");
            fp.ID = "fp" + placeholder.Controls.Count.ToString();
            placeholder.Controls.Add(fp);
        }

    }
```

This control load carefully. but I have problem by save data from this controls. I use this code but didn't work. ( placeholder.controls.count is always 0)

```
private void SaveFilters()
    {
        int count = 0;
        if (ViewState["count"] != null)
        {
            count = (int)ViewState["count"];
        }
        string str=string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i <= placeholder.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
             Common.FilterParameters fp = (Common.FilterParameters)placeholder.FindControl("fp"+i.ToString());
            if(fp!=null)
            {

                string param = fp.filterparamText;
                string rule = fp.RuleText;                  
                   str+="{"+param+"+"+rule+"}";


            }
        }
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        {
         save(str);
        }
    }
```

how can I get data from this user control?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your "SaveFilters" method is being called when the webform posts back, either from the Page Load event or from the event that caused the postback (eg a button click event).

You need to reload all of your dynamic controls on every postback if you want to be able to read their values.  The typical pattern is to add dynamic controls from the Page Init event.  The Asp.Net runtime assigns values to the controls from the form after Page Init. You can read those values from the Page Load event or from the event that caused the postback (eg a button click event).

If you do not re-add the dynamic controls the Asp.net runtime has nowhere to place the values from the form, and so those values are lost.

So, for dynamic controls:
1.  Load them in the Page Init event every time the page posts back.
2.  Read values from them in the Page Load event or in the event that caused the postback (eg a button click event).

Comment: i add CreateControls() in init but didn't work again and  placeholder.controls.count is 0.